# If the two cars meet at any point print yes else no?

Tags: java

Here x1 and v1 are initial position and velocity of car1, and x2 and v2 for car2. I need to find if the two cars meet at any point. It gives me error displaying "No" always.Any suggestions?

```
    if (v1 > v2) {
        while ((x1 + (v1 * i)) > (x2 + (v2 * i))) {
            if ((x1 + (v1 * i)) == (x2 + (v2 * i))) {
                prime = true;
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(""+i);
            i++;
        }
        if (prime == true) {
            s = "Yes";
        } else {
            s = "No";
        }
    }
    if (v2 > v1) {
        while ((x2 + (v2 * i)) > (x1 + (v1 * i))) {
            if ((x1 + (v1 * i)) == (x2 + (v2 * i))) {
                prime = true;
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(""+i);
            i++;
        }
        if (prime == true) {
            s = "Yes";
        } else {
            s = "No";
        }
    }
    if (v1 == v2) {
        if (x1 == x2) {
            s = "Yes";
        } else s = "No";
    }
    System.out.println(""+s);

}
```

}

Comment: They go linear? Just in X direction ? And you work with integers?

Comment: Just for clarification, are they both traveling in the same direction or opposite directions? You’re trying to find if they share the same position correct? Your code looks a lot more complicated then it needs to be so may try checking your math again to make sure you didn’t miss anything.

Comment: I would suppose they are either going in opposite directions away from each other, or meet at a non-integer `i`, so the equalities never hold. Print out their positions at each step and you'll see what happens.

Answer (score 5):

This is a mathematical question not so much a programming one. Basically you don't need any loops and stuff to answer it. I assume (since there are no other implications) that both cars go in the same X direction with speed V where both X and V are positive numbers.

So basically your logic can be -> If the faster car is behind the slower one they will eventually meet.  Otherwise they won't. And in this case you won't need any loops. The last check in the example below is if they are already in the same spot.

```
   if((x1<x2 && v1>v2) || (x1>x2 && v1<v2) || (x1==x2)) { 
        System.out.println("Yes");
    } else { 
       System.out.println("No");
    }
```

If V can be negative (for example to show going backwards which is a bit strange way because velosity cannot be negative) then it is still the same. You might go for a loop only if you want to know the point on the vector X where they met. But with some calculations you can still calculate it without loops. For example :

```
int vDiff=Math.abs(v1-v2);      
int xDiff=Math.abs(x1-x2);      
System.out.println("Meeting point: "+(((double)xDiff)/((double)vDiff)*v1+x1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're complicating the problem, with your iterations you're essentially finding the time step at which the cars meet, if they do meet.

There are actually only five possibilities for these two cars, when considered in one direction:

1) Car 1 is ahead of car 2, and moving faster than or the same speed as car 2 => Cars never meet

2) Car 1 is behind car 2, and moving faster than car 2 => Cars meet

3) Car 1 is ahead of car 2, and moving slower than car 2 => Cars meet

4) Car 1 is behind car 2, and moving slower than or the same speed as car 2 => Cars never meet

5) Cars have already met.

In code this might look like the following:

```
boolean carsMeet(x1,v1,x2,v2){
    boolean output = false;

    if(x1 > x2){
        // Conditions 1 and 3. Car 1 is ahead of car 2
        if (v2 > v1){
            // Condition 3
            output = true;
        }

    } else if (x1 < x2){
        // Conditions 2 and 4. Car 2 is ahead of car 1
        if (v1 > v2){
            // Condition 2
            output = true;
        }

    } else {
        // Condition 5. Car 1 has already met car 2
        output = true;
    }

return output;

}
```

I haven't run this code to check it for syntax errors, but in general this is how I advise tackling the problem, rather than your current approach.

Comment: Do you only drive on one-way streets?

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "No";
if (x1 == x2) {
   s = "Yes";
} else if (v1 == v2) {
   s = "No";
} else if ((x2-x1)/(v1-v2) > 0) {
   s = "Yes";
}
```

Comment: add some explanation to it.